# How to update the SS58Prefix for a running node?

Tags: rpc, ss58format

If I have started running a Substrate node but the `ss58Format` value in the chain specification .json file that is generated from using the `build-spec` command is not `42`, how do I update the chain so its `SS58` Format is 42?

20220329 add:

> i have updated system's SS58Prefix(set SS58Prefix=42),and upgrade wasm, but the ss58Format  from rpc's response is not 42

how to update rpc's ss58Format?

```
const res = await api.rpc.system.properties()
console.log(res)

# ss58Format is not 42.
```

Comment: have you tried initiating a forkless runtime upgrade by following this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/forkless-upgrades/ where the change you make is modifying the `SS58Prefix` value here https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L141

Answer (score 2):

The chain spec is no longer a canonical place to store the SS58 Prefix for a chain.

Instead you should use the `SS58Prefix` configuration constant in `frame_system`:

```rust
/// The designated SS85 prefix of this chain.
///
/// This replaces the "ss58Format" property declared in the chain spec. Reason is
/// that the runtime should know about the prefix in order to make use of it as
/// an identifier of the chain.
#[pallet::constant]
type SS58Prefix: Get<u16>;
```

This is how things like Polkadot JS API get the appropriate SS58 for your chain.

For your node binary, you want to be sure to call:

```
sp_core::crypto::set_default_ss58_version(ss58_version);
```

This value can come from the the runtime, or you can program whatever functionality you want. For example, in Polkadot, we don't actually pull the value from the chain spec, we just check which chainspec has been loaded, and then pull the SS58 from the [registry](https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry):

```rust
fn set_default_ss58_version(spec: &Box<dyn service::ChainSpec>) {
    let ss58_version = if spec.is_kusama() {
        Ss58AddressFormatRegistry::KusamaAccount
    } else if spec.is_westend() {
        Ss58AddressFormatRegistry::SubstrateAccount
    } else {
        Ss58AddressFormatRegistry::PolkadotAccount
    }
    .into();

    sp_core::crypto::set_default_ss58_version(ss58_version);
}
```

Comment: Did a query on the URL you provided - under Developer -> Chain state -> Constants the `system.ss58Prefix` Shawn referenced returns 42.

Answer (score 1):

42 is the default development prefix. To register an own prefix add it to the global registry - https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry.

Next update your on-chain system.ss58Prefix constant to reflect the above value and then udate the chain-spec (only needed for RPC nodes, most probably only used as a fallback where the on-chain constant is not available)

Comment: BTW, how to update chain-spec for a running node?

Comment: Note that the ss58 registry is for non-test networks.

Comment: how update rpc response's ss58Format?

Comment: Here is an example of how to update the chain spec: https://github.com/interlay/interbtc/commit/431937276b9197a373855b084b97dfa931d8273d